# Send email with Mandrill and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, mandrill

I'm trying to use Mandrill to send an email using an AngularJS controller.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="emailApp">
<section ng-controller="ContactCtrl as contact">
  <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" ng-submit="contactForm.$valid && sendTheMail()" novalidate>
    Name: <input type="text" id="userName" required><br>
    Email: <input type="email" id="userEmail" required><br>
    Subject: <input type="text" id="userSubject" required><br>
    Message: <textarea type="text" id="userMessage" required>
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitBtn">
  </form>
</section>
</body>
```

AngularJS

```
    angular.module('emailApp', []);

    angular.module('emailApp').controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.sendTheMail = function() {
        // create a new instance of the Mandrill class with your API key
        var m = new mandrill.Mandrill('my_api_key');
        // Collect Inputs
        var email = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
        var name = document.getElementById('userName').value;
        var subject = document.getElementById('userSubject').value;
        var message = document.getElementById('userMessage').value;
        var emailBody = "From: " + name + "<br><br>" +  + "Subject: " + subject + "<br><br>" + message;

        var params = {

            "message": {
                "from_email":email,
                "to":[{"email":"myemail@hotmail.com"}],
                "subject": "New email from website",
                "html": emailBody
            }
        };

        m.messages.send(params);
      };

    }]);
```

I don't get any errors from the console, but I know that the email is not being sent.

Edit:
I don't know why the email wasn't being sent earlier, must be something to do with my free Mandrill key. This is working for me now.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your problem is either with Angular or with Mandrill. Rather than leaving the whole problem here, determine which it is (is your function executing at all? if you execute the Mandrill code by itself, does it work?). Once you have that, edit your question to only include your actual problem.

Comment: On a side node, are you sure you want to use Mandrill from javascript? You're giving your API key away to every client who can see this page, giving them the ability to send messages on your behalf. If this is on the public internet, bad stuff can happen.

Comment: I sadly only know javascript html and css right now. I was thinking of maybe learning php just for this email part of the website though i'm not sure how complicated it would be.

Comment: To answer your question earlier, my javascript was working before I moved it into an angular controller, but it felt dirty using `ng-submit=""` and `onsubmit=""` plus i had to do my own javascript form validation manually.. when I tried to revert it back to test it again, it hasn't been working so it's frustrating. I'm thinking of putting this on hold if i can.